# Docker Desktop can't start at first time in Windows 10

Tags: windows, boot, docker, docker-for-windows, start

I click on the Docker Desktop icon, the Docker upload window appears and after some time it closes, I repeat these steps about 5 times to start successfully. I am using Windows 10 Pro, my processor is Intel Core i7-6500, 16GB RAM. How could y make that starts at first time, thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Windows 11 and now It works perfectly Docker Desktop, it runs at first time, (Installed with wsl2 and alpine from Microsoft Store)